# Paypal custom creditcard form with subscription - NEXTJS

Tags: node.js, next.js, paypal, payment-gateway

I have successfully created subscription with nodeJS using the following code:

```
const createSubscription = async () => {
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken();

  const response = await axios.post(
    `${PAYPAL_API}/v1/billing/subscriptions`,
    {
      plan_id: subscriptionPlanId,
      application_context: {
        brand_name: "test",
        locale: "en-US",
        user_action: "SUBSCRIBE_NOW",
        return_url: "https://test.test/",
        cancel_url: "https://test.test/",
        shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
      },
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    }
  );

  return response.data;
};
```

and this is the response im getting:

```
{
  status: 'APPROVAL_PENDING',
  id: 'I-YUSWK0P891TV',
  create_time: '2024-02-03T15:03:29Z',
  links: [
    {
      href: 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions?ba_token=BA-97806019K4147340Y',
      rel: 'approve',
      method: 'GET'
    },
    {
      href: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-YUSWK0P891TV',
      rel: 'edit',
      method: 'PATCH'
    },
    {
      href: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-YUSWK0P891TV',
      rel: 'self',
      method: 'GET'
    }
  ]
}
```

What im looking to do is being able to customize the whole proccess of approval without using the approve link generated, does paypal allow me to do so? if yes any direction may help me.
Thanks!

I have tried to use paypalSDK:

```
import {
  PayPalScriptProvider,
  PayPalHostedFieldsProvider,
  PayPalHostedField,
  usePayPalHostedFields,
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
```

but its mainly used to 1 time payment.

Answer (score 0):

For a Subscription to be approved, you need to either redirect a payer to the provided 'approve' URL (an old integration pattern, for old websites), or (the recommended flow) use the PayPal JS SDK (via react-paypal-js in your case) to render a Subscribe button, with a `createSubscription` callback that obtains the created subscription's id for approval when clicked.

The react-paypal-js storybook [has an example](https://paypal.github.io/react-paypal-js/?path=/docs/example-subscriptions--default) that uses a client-side `actions.subscription.create`; replace this with a fetch call to a server route that creates the subscription and returns the JSON result in your question.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import {
    PayPalScriptProvider,
    PayPalButtons,
    usePayPalScriptReducer
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

const ButtonWrapper = ({ type }) => {
    const [{ options }, dispatch] = usePayPalScriptReducer();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch({
            type: "resetOptions",
            value: {
                ...options,
                intent: "subscription",
            },
        });
    }, [type]);

    return (<PayPalButtons
        createSubscription={(data, actions) => {
            return actions.subscription
                .create({
                    plan_id: "P-3RX065706M3469222L5IFM4I",
                })
                .then((orderId) => {
                    // Your code here after create the order
                    return orderId;
                });
        }}
        style={{
            label: "subscribe",
        }}
    />);
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <PayPalScriptProvider
            options={{
                clientId: "test",
                components: "buttons",
                intent: "subscription",
                vault: true,
            }}
        >
            <ButtonWrapper type="subscription" />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
    );
}
```